# Using Arraylist display data of questions and answers

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-studio, arraylist

i want to show questions in list view from sqlite and under every question there is editText field to submit answer. i am fetching questions from local db through array list, but problem is when user will submit answer then next question will be displayed in list and so on.
kindly help me how to do it?

Comment: which way you currently display show efforts

Comment: i want to show that first display question and then ask user to submit answer. when user enters the answer and then display next question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did it by passing a variable in constructor. and showed 3 question one after the other in my scenario. and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Store data in DB in sequence with number as primary key

While fetching question from SQLite in query add

`limit Question_Number`
Question_Number is the question limit you want to display.

First time add `limit 1`

Everytime when user enter answer the question and click ok.
Fetch the data from database using `limit currentPosition +1`